# JQL to find epics that are not linked to a theme

Tags: jira, jql

I can't find any examples of how to do this.

I want to filter all epics that are not linked to any issues of type "theme".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I belive there's no JQL you can do without any add-on purchased.

If you can, try [scriptrunner](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/index.html).

There you can do something like,

```
issuetype = Epic AND issueFunction not in hasLinkType("Epic-Story Link")
```

This gets results of all the epic issues with no issue linked expect Epic.

**"issueFunction" is possible JQL only if you add ScriptRunner add-on.**

Basically, in the Epic issue, "Issues In Epic", if there's no issues is in Epic, then it will be on the result.

For specific "theme" issue type, then you need to develop more with this script.

Answer (score 0):

Not with JQL that I know of. I think that I would use Jira python to get the issue link information and filter out the unwanted epics

Answer (score 0):

You can filter Epics with no theme with something like this: `Type = Epic AND "Parent Link" is EMPTY AND resolution  = Unresolved`